# Searching a huge number of strings from Excel to a large number of Text files

Tags: vba, excel

I have written this code to get the input string from the spreadsheet and search the string across the text files and state whether or not it is found in the Excel sheet.

Scenario:

**Excel (sheet1):**

> ```
> ColumnA
>
> AAA 
>
> BBB
> ```

**Drive C:**

**C:** should be give in Column D5.

It has subfolders TEMP1, TEMP2, ...

- **Folder C:\TEMP1\**

  It has these text files:

  - X1.txt (has content AAA)
  - X2.txt (doesn't have any search data)
- **Folder C:\TEMP2\**

  It has these text files:

  - Y1.txt (has content BBB)
  - Y2.txt (doesn't have any search data)

```
Public K As Integer
Dim fs As Object
Dim fso As Object
Public fpth As String
Public str As String

Public Sub SearchInSQSDatabase_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets(1)

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Sheets(2)

K = 2

Dim i As Integer
i = 1
ws2.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Search String"
ws2.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Files"
ws2.Cells(1, 6).Value = "Comments"

Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
     'ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
     str = Cells(i, 1).Value
     ShowFolderList (ws1.Cells(5, 4).Value)
     i = i + 1
Loop


End Sub
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Get the List of Files and folders
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub ShowFolderList(folderspec)
   On Error GoTo local_err

 Dim f, f1, fc, s, sFldr

 Dim ws2 As Worksheet
 Set ws2 = Sheets(2)

 Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set f = fs.GetFolder(folderspec)
 Set fc = f.SubFolders

  For Each f1 In fc
     ' If Right(f1, 1) <> "\" Then ShowFolderList f1 & "\" Else ShowFolderList f1
     If Right(f1, 1) <> "\" Then ShowFolderList f1 Else ShowFolderList f1
  Next
Set fc = f.Files
For Each f1 In fc
    ' ws2.Cells(K, 4).Value = folderspec & "\" & f1.Name
    fpth = folderspec & "\" & f1.Name
    StringExistsInFile (f1.Name)

    'K = K + 1
Next
local_exit:
     Exit Sub
 local_err:
    MsgBox Err & " " & Err.Description
    Resume local_exit
    Resume
 End Sub

 ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 'Check for the String
 ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub StringExistsInFile(fname)
Dim theString, callString As String
Dim path As String 
Dim StrFile As String
Dim file
Dim line As String
Dim flag As String

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Sheets(2)

theString = str
path = fpth
StrFile = Dir(path)

Do While StrFile <> ""

'Find TheString in the file
'If found, debug.print and exit loop

Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(path)
Do While Not file.AtEndOfLine
    line = file.ReadLine
    If InStr(1, line, theString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ws2.Cells(K, 4).Value = str
        ws2.Cells(K, 5).Value = fname
        ws2.Cells(K, 6).Value = "Srting is found"
        flag = "Y"
    End If


Loop

file.Close
Set file = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

StrFile = Dir()
Loop
If flag = "Y" Then
   K = K + 1
 Else
  ws2.Cells(K, 4).Value = str
  ws2.Cells(K, 5).Value = fname
  ws2.Cells(K, 6).Value = "String is not Found"
   K = K + 1
  End If


  End Sub
```

**Output:**

Output should be written in sheet2:

> ```
> ColumnA columnB 
>
> AAA     X1 
>
> BBB     Y1
> ```

I have updated the code to have a hyperlink in the text file name to open the text file for the strings that are found, also need to no the count of column

added the below logic at the end, I feel the below code can be written in better way

```
Do While ws2.Cells(K, 6).Value <> ""
    K = K + 1
 Loop


Do While j < K

If ws2.Cells(j, 7).Value <> "" Then

    ws2.Cells(j, 7).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws2.Cells(j, 7), Address:= _
    ws2.Cells(j, 7).Value, TextToDisplay:=ws2.Cells(j, 7).Value

    ' ws2.Cells(j, 7).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & ws2.Cells(j, 7) & ",    Address = " & ws2.Cells(j, 7).Value & ")"
    'ws2.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=j, _
    'Address:=ws2.Cells(j, 7).Value, TextToDisplay:=ws2.Cells(j, 7).Value

    End If
  j = j + 1
Loop
```

Comment: This code takes time when dealing with mare search strings and more number of text files

Answer (score 5):

A few suggestions:

1. Most obvious (and simple) step is to read the entire file, and not one line at the time

   Change this:

   ```
   Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(Path)
   Do While Not file.AtEndOfLine
       Line = file.ReadLine
       If InStr(1, Line, theString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
           ws2.Cells(K, 4).Value = Str
           ws2.Cells(K, 5).Value = fname
           ws2.Cells(K, 6).Value = "Srting is found"
           flag = "Y"
       End If
   Loop
   ```

   To this:

   ```
   Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(Path)

   fullFile = file.ReadAll

   If InStr(1, fullFile, theString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
       With ws2
           .Cells(K, 4).Value2 = theString
           .Cells(K, 5).Value2 = fname
       End With
       flag = "Y"
   End If
   ```

   It eliminates the do-while loop. More [details about `.ReadAll()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRary/t58aa4dd(v=vs.84).aspx).
2. Store `Str` and `fname` info into an array, then commit the entire array to the worksheet at the end, instead of writing to each cell separately.
3. The "Find" command in DOS might be faster and it can also provide the line number(s) where the string is found:

   **Find** /?

   Searches for a text string in a file or files.

   FIND [/V] [/C] [/N] [/I] [/OFF[LINE]] "string" [[drive:][path]filename[ ...]]

Comment: Thank you Paul. Do the size of the array needs to be determined rt? If am defining a dynamic array I need to fix the size to a point right. In that case I may lose the values. Am I missing anything?

Comment: There is some guess work to determine the size of the array, but if you know from the start that you'll never have to deal with more than let's say a maximum of 10,000 files (or 100,000), you could initialize the array like this memArr = Range("A1:B10000"), or something similar, just grab the range where you'll want to dump the results at the end. Give yourself enough room so you'll never lose any data (considering any future expansions). If the array you create is way too large, before writing it to the sheet redim it to the total files found (just once)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @paul bica about the use of `.ReadAll` but just wanted to add a couple extra points about your code (but then see point 7).

1. In your original code in `StringExistsInFile` you should remember to quit the loop once the string is found. Otherwise you will continue to needlessly read the rest of the file.

   ```
   Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(Path)
   Do While Not file.AtEndOfLine
       Line = file.ReadLine
       If InStr(1, Line, theString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
           ws2.Cells(K, 4).Value = Str
           ws2.Cells(K, 5).Value = fname
           ws2.Cells(K, 6).Value = "Srting is found"
           flag = "Y"
           ' Remember to quit the loop
           Exit Do
       End If
   Loop
   ```
2. In `ShowFolderList` there are some things to refine: you're not defining most of the variable types (`Dim f, f1, fc, s, sFldr`) and you've got an `If ... Then ... Else ...` which is redundant because both give the same outcome. You re-use the `f1` variable but the first time it represents `Folder` objects and the second time `File` objects. Best not to re-use variables, maybe simple loop counters are ok but definitely shouldn't refer them to different things.
3. In `StringExistsInFile` you've got a bunch of variable assignments that aren't needed and generally confuse what is happening:

   ```
   theString = str 
   path = fpth  
   StrFile = Dir(path)
   ```

   You are using `StrFile = Dir(path)` and a `Do While ... Loop` but you then open `fso.OpenTextFile(path)`. You already know that the file exists so you don't need to re-check it. The `Dir(string)` function with a `Do While ... Loop` is usually used when `string` contains some wildcards and you want to loop through all the matching files.

   The `Else` block in this code looks like you want to report whether every string occurs in every file but your output isn't clear on this point:

   ```
   If flag = "Y" Then
       K = K + 1
   Else
       ws2.Cells(K, 4).Value = str
       ws2.Cells(K, 5).Value = fname
       ws2.Cells(K, 6).Value = "String is not Found"
       K = K + 1
   End If
   ```
4. It is a good idea to avoid module-level variables because they make it difficult to track which code assigns & changes the value of the variable. You can pass variables and object references between procs. Also, when you use the `Cells` method always qualify it with the worksheet and, ideally, the workbook. Sometimes you are using the worksheet and other times not.
5. Use early binding for `FileSystemObject` and `Dictionary` it makes writing the code much easier. In the VBA IDE, go Tools -> References and find and select the Microsoft Scripting Runtime.
6. Indentation makes the code much easier to look at and to see at a glance where procs start & end. I indent everything except proc declarations and `Dim` statements but some people indent the latter as well.
7. It has just occurred to me that the slow part (relatively) of your code will be reading the file because it involves disk access. So it will probably be faster to read all your strings into an array or dictionary, then load the file into memory and loop through the array or dictionary looking for matches. If you use a dictionary the value of each key can be the count of the number of times it was found which then lets you do a summary at the end of those strings that were not found at all.

Here is the code that I ended up with

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SearchInSQSDatabase_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim outputRange As Range
Dim stringToFind As String
Dim callString As String
Dim dictOfStrings As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim dictKey As Variant
Dim i As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

    i = 1
    ws2.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Search String"
    ws2.Cells(1, 5).Value = "Files"
    ws2.Cells(1, 6).Value = "Comments"
    Set outputRange = ws2.Cells(2, 4)

    ' dictionary will be all the strings to find with a count
    ' of the number of times they were found
    Set dictOfStrings = New Dictionary

    Do While ws1.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:=1).Value <> ""
         'ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
         stringToFind = CStr(ws1.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:=1).Value)
         ' Cannot add the same value to dictionary twice
         If Not dictOfStrings.Exists(stringToFind) Then
            dictOfStrings.Add stringToFind, 0
            callString = "CALL " & stringToFind
            dictOfStrings.Add callString, 0
         Else
            MsgBox stringToFind & " exists in your list more than once."
         End If
         i = i + 1
    Loop


    ShowFolderList ws1.Cells(5, 4).Value, dictOfStrings, outputRange

    ' If only want a  summary of which strings do not exist in any files
    ' then do it here
    For Each dictKey In dictOfStrings.Keys
        stringToFind = CStr(dictKey)
        If dictOfStrings.Item(stringToFind) = 0 Then
            With outputRange
                .Value = stringToFind
                .Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value = ""
                .Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value = "String NOT found in any files"
            End With
            Set outputRange = outputRange.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
        End If
    Next dictKey

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Looks in startingFolder and all subfolders at each file
'and calls StringsExistInFile for each file
'Recursive proc, i.e calls itself for each subfolder.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub ShowFolderList(ByRef startingFolder As String, ByRef dictOfStrings As Scripting.Dictionary, ByRef outputRange As Range)

On Error GoTo local_err

Dim fileSystem As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim topFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim subFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim thisFile As Scripting.File

    Set fileSystem = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set topFolder = fileSystem.GetFolder(startingFolder)

    ' Code needs to call itself for every subfolder found
    For Each subFolder In topFolder.SubFolders
        ShowFolderList subFolder.path, dictOfStrings, outputRange
    Next subFolder

    For Each thisFile In topFolder.Files
        StringsExistInFile thisFile, dictOfStrings, outputRange
    Next thisFile

local_exit:
    Exit Sub
local_err:
    MsgBox Err & " " & Err.Description
    Resume local_exit
    Resume
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Check for each String in theFile. Writes the result
'to the output range
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Private Sub StringsExistInFile(ByRef theFile As Scripting.File, ByRef dictOfStrings As Scripting.Dictionary, ByRef outputRange As Range)

Dim inputStream As Scripting.TextStream
Dim fullFile As String
Dim stringToFind As String
Dim dictKey As Variant
Dim foundOk As Boolean

    Set inputStream = theFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

    fullFile = inputStream.ReadAll
    inputStream.Close

    ' Loops through the dictionary of strings to find
    For Each dictKey In dictOfStrings.Keys
        stringToFind = CStr(dictKey)
        If InStr(1, fullFile, stringToFind, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            foundOk = True
            ' Update the count in dictionary
            dictOfStrings.Item(stringToFind) = dictOfStrings.Item(stringToFind) + 1
        Else
            foundOk = False
        End If
' ************************************************************
' Uncomment whichever block of code is relevant for your needs
' ************************************************************
        ' If only want to say if the string *was* found in this file
'        If foundOk Then
'            With outputRange
'                .Value = stringToFind
'                .Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value = theFile.Name
'                .Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value = "String is found"
'            End With
'            Set outputRange = outputRange.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
'        End If
        ' But if want to say whether every string was found or not in every file
        With outputRange
            .Value = stringToFind
            .Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value = theFile.Name
            If foundOk Then
                .Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value = "String is found"
            Else
                .Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value = "String NOT found"
            End If
        End With
        Set outputRange = outputRange.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
    Next dictKey

End Sub
```

Comment: All very good points ! I didn't pay close attention to the code before the reading of the file. One other thing to mention: I wouldn't report anything related to the files NOT containing the searched string. I consider "String is not Found" to be white noise, not relevant to process, especially when working with a large number of files (is there a need to know the name of each file not containing the string?)

Comment: Thank you Chips!!! Also I need to add few conditions to the string, Like I need to find String value is present or not along with "CALL stringvalue" is present or not .... When I tried that I am getting the LAST string as "Not Found in any files".. please find the updated code

Comment: `callString = "CALL " & stringToFind
       
         If Not dictOfStrings.Exists(stringToFind) Then
            dictOfStrings.Add stringToFind, 0
            dictOfStrings.Add callString, 0
         Else
            MsgBox stringToFind & " exists in your list more than once."
         End If
         i = i + 1`

Comment: I wanted to align but not sure y it ended up like above

Comment: I have added the callString variable and related code to my answer. Nothing immediately looks wrong. Do you mean the last string in your list or "LAST"?

Comment: Thank you ChipsLetten !!! In the Summary part am receiving the message XXX "String NOT found in any files" , not sure whether it is a case sensitive issue, because I have XXX (FIrst cell ) & YYY (Second Cell) as a search string and got XXX & CALL XXX and only YYY in the text file. The result is written as expected ... YYY samp.txt string found & CALL YYY samp.txt String NOT found and also I am getting a value YYY   String NOT found in any files

Comment: Can you post your code as a new question on [se] where it will easier to check it?

Comment: Found the problem. Will fix it in my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Done. Of course if you search for "XXX" and "CALL XXX" both will say they have been found if your file contains "CALL XXX".

Comment: Thank you ChipsLetten !!!  One more thing comes to my mind ... Is it possible to have a link to open a text file when the search string is found in the text file ? If so we can write the link to a separate column....

Comment: That is really a separate question for [so]. Use the macro recorder when you create/insert a hyperlink and then tweak that code.